# Proper way to update the list of records in table using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In my Education Programme database table, I have 3 records for one specific student

[image]

so I want to remove **P3** program from this person list, so in font-end its showing like like this

[image]

once I click Delete, specific **P3** remove from frontend and model and once hit **save** button it's passing to the backend code **P1**, **P2** as a list.

I'm using the **entity framework** for database transactions.

looking for your advice here on

- Should I delete all existing records and then insert **P1**, **P2** again.
  Or
- DO I need iterate each record by comparing list I'm sending vs existing records and attach **P1**, **P2** and find out missing one and delete 
  Or
- this type of transaction can EF do itself

Looking forward which way is recommended

Comment: It might be a bit fragile to go for option 1. Option 2 sounds okay, but what option 1 and 2 have in common is that you'll need to query the database one time to send the list to the view, then a second time to get the list from the database to compare the differences and then a third time to delete and update any items that might have changed. That's hitting the DB a lot. You might come up with a solution where you use a `deleted` and `edited` flag that you can use to `Update()` or `Remove()` the edited/deleted rows.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go for second option since its better approach to remove missing records rather than remove all records.

'Missing' items from a collection are not considered to be deleted.

So what you'll need to do is mark the items for deletion yourself. Something like this:

```
public void Update(Programme record)
{
    var missingRows = dB.ProgrammeRows.Where(i => i.ProgrammeId == record.ProgrammeId)
                        .Except(record.Rows);
    dB.ProgrammeRows.RemoveRange(missingRows);

    dB.Programmes.Update(record);
    dB.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the class should be as follows:

```
   public class ProgrammeRow
   {
        public int ProgrammeId { get; set; }
        public string ProgrammeName { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student{ get; set; }
   }

   public class Programme
   {
        public int ProgrammeId { get; set; }
        private ICollection<ProgrammeRow> _rows;
        public virtual ICollection<ProgrammeRow> Rows => _rows ?? (_rows = new List<ProgrammeRow>());
   }
```

Comment: Thanks lot Vignesh let me apply first and let you know

Comment: This seems to be a pretty common approach, from what I've seen. Everywhere I've worked, this sort of approach has been taken to achieve this sort of thing